# What is a seamless table?

Tags: mapinfo, table, seamless

A client has asked me to provide a dataset in seamless table format. Could anybody describe to me what a seamless table is?
I understand that it is a format used by mapinfo, but can I create a seamless table in some other way, by FME for example?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not ask your client what *they* think a "seamless table" is? Their understanding--which could be unconventional--might be different from any answer you can find elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A seamless table is an index table referencing other MapInfo tables (raster and/or vector) thru these tables MBR, Minimum Bounding Rectangle.

If you open a seamless table into a map window in MapInfo Professional you will not see the data from the table itself, but MapInfo Professional will open the tables which MBR is inside the current view of the map.

The seamless table holds only very litte data itself: a column holding path and file name of the table and a spatial object illustrating the MBR of the data in the table

In the Tool Manager of MapInfo Professional you'll find a tool called Seamless Manager. This tool will help you create a Seamless table.

Comment: I understand a little bit more about seamless tables now. I realise now that I was confused by the use of the word "table" by Mapinfo.

Answer (score 0):

We use both MapInfo and FME at my workplace, but sadly the guys who know this stuff are away today. I wonder if this might help answer your question?

[FMEPedia Answer](http://fmepedia.safe.com/AnswersQuestionDetail?id=906a0000000cfq1AAA)

Sounds like it is not an easy thing to do in FME.

Hopethat helps in some way?

Answer (score 0):

They probably mean [MapInfo's version of a Raster Catalog](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/catalog-images-seamless-table-td4887023.html). If you're dealing with image data, then I would assume this is what they're looking for.

It doesn't sound like they're easy to make with FME, based on the link in Rob Quincey's answer.