# Merging Raster Images in MapInfo?

Tags: raster, mapinfo

I have a bunch of MapInfo Tables in raster format (.tab / .grd) that I would like to consolidate into one table.

Is this possible within MapInfo?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is called "seamless" table. You will find a MBX tool "Seamless Manager".

*Tools/Seamless Manager/New Seamless Table*

This tool will help you create a Seamless table.

You should check also:

[What is a seamless table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59825/what-is-a-seamless-table)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large amount of tab files to combine using the seamless manager, it is worth creating the fields first in excel then pasting this into your workspace using a text editor.

[image: Excel Snippet]

start by searching in the directory containing the tab files for '.tab' then select all the files hold **'shift'** and **'right click'** then select copy as path.

Paste this into the second column, then paste columns 1, 3 and 4 down to the bottom. The fith column is basically a combination of all the created fields using: **=CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2)**

paste all the fields of that column into your workspace file then open the workspace.

It will be slow to load but will mean all your tables are ready to be appended to the seamless table.