# Index TAB for large raster files

Tags: raster, mapinfo, aerial-photography, orthophoto, map-index

I received a batch of aerial images along with an index file that essentially tells me which aerial image covers each 20x20km tile. Can I also create this type of index TAB through MapInfo?

[image]

Comment: Gosh, blast from the past I forgot about these. Pretty sure those .tabs are text, have a look with a good text editor. Very easy to program their creation if you need

Comment: And see for a possible alternative http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html

Comment: Thanks @mdsumner, I'll check it out. Looks like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo Pro comes with a tool called Seamless Manager that will let you create a seamless table referring to all the aerial images.

In this way you can just open the seamless table which will open that necessary images for the current map extent. In the layer control you will however only see the seamless table listed.

In an [earlier discussion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59825/what-is-a-seamless-table) the seamless table was discussed.

Answer (score 0):

@mdsummer:

Gosh, blast from the past I forgot about these. Pretty sure those .tabs are text, have a look with a good text editor. Very easy to program their creation if you need.

And see for a possible alternative gdal.org/gdaltindex.html