# Cannot open .TAB files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, tab

I have a bunch of .tab files, which are created by Mapinfo, but some of them cannot be opened in QGIS, for example:
This "Urkarten.Tab" have 4 files ( Urkarten.dat, Urkarten.id, Urkarten.map, Urkarten.tab ), I tried to open it in QGIS 3.16, but an error occurred "Layer is not valid : The layer is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason".

The tab data content is as follows:

[image]

Comment: is it possible, that your layer is empty? In my experience Qgis does not like empty .TAB tables. If not, could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Are also all the other tab files that do not open seamless tables? See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59825/what-is-a-seamless-table

Comment: IsSeamless=TRUE jumps out at me, been years since I used MapInfo but I remember something about seamless layers being some sort of virtual layer that is a composite of multiple layers/tiles so maybe that is why QGIS thinks it is not valid

Comment: I looked at another file that couldn't be opened, and IsSeamless was also TRUE, they exist in Mapinfo as a raster-like file. Is there any way to load such files in QGIS?